# Changing a cloned array via Array.prototype.slice() affects the original

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function ConwayNeighbours(a) {
var b = a.slice()
for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
for(j=0; j<a[i].length; j++){

    if(a[i][j+1])
        b[i][j]++
    if(a[i][j-1])
        b[i][j]++

    if(a[i-1]){
        if(a[i-1][j])
            b[i][j]++
        if(a[i-1][j+1])
            b[i][j]++
        if(a[i-1][j-1])
            b[i][j]++
    }

    if(a[i+1]){
        if(a[i+1][j])
            b[i][j]++
        if(a[i+1][j+1])
            b[i][j]++
        if(a[i+1][j-1])
            b[i][j]++
    }
console.log("i",i,"j",j,"a",a,"b",b)
}

return b
}
ConwayNeighbours([[false,true],  [true,true]])
```

my question is why and how did the array `a` did change, i'm not doing any affectaion and i made sure to clone it via [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) that returns a new array from the original one, can someone explain

Comment: From the doc you referenced:
slice returns a shallow copy of elements from the original array.

For object references, if a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice returns a shallow copy of an array, so if you have an array of arrays, the array references will be copied as-is. One shortcut to doing a deep copy of an array, depending on the types of your data members, is to do the following instead of `b=a.slice()`:

```
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Alternatively, you can use a recursive array deep-cloning function such as this one [by Andrew Ray](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-clone-a-nested-array-in-javascript/):

```
function arrayClone( arr ) {

    var i, copy;

    if( Array.isArray( arr ) ) {
        copy = arr.slice( 0 );
        for( i = 0; i < copy.length; i++ ) {
            copy[ i ] = arrayClone( copy[ i ] );
        }
        return copy;
    } else if( typeof arr === 'object' ) {
        throw 'Cannot clone array containing an object!';
    } else {
        return arr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is pass by reference and var a contains a nested array. You're only slicing (and ergo copying) the top level array for B, but the value still remains the array contained in A. You can test this easily in the console:

```
var a = [[1,2,3,4]]
var b = a.slice()

b === a //false
b[0] === a[0] //true
```